# Spring AOP before annotation is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am trying to implement AOP concept using Spring Boot. But before annotation is not working. 
This is my code,

POM.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Application.properties

```
server.port=6500
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

Main:

package com.techno.theater;

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.techno.theater.services.SampleService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DigitalTheaterApplication {

     private static  Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(DigitalTheaterApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DigitalTheaterApplication.class, args);
        new SampleService().sample();

    }
}
```

Sample Service:

```
package com.techno.theater.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SampleService {
    public void sample(){
        System.out.println("Sample method inovking");
    }
}
```

Aspect class

```
package com.techno.theater.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectService {

    @Before("execution(* com.techno.theater.services.SampleService.sample())")
    public void beforeSampleMethod() {
        System.out.println("Sample method aspect");
    }

}
```

Here I am invoking sample method from DigitalTheaterApplication class but before execute this method my aspect method should be executed but it's not working am not sure do I need to add some configuration.

Comment: Works as it should. You are creating a new instance yourself, you should use the instance created by the application context.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you help answer this **[transaction-management-does-not-working-when-using-configuration-and-aspectj-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254391/transaction-management-does-not-working-when-using-configuration-and-aspectj-in)**,please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DigitalTheaterApplication.class, args);
    new SampleService().sample();
}
```

The code above is the problem, to be precise the `new SampleService().sample();` is what is flawed in your code. You are creating a new instance outside the scope of Spring and as such it will not be exposed to AOP.

Instead what you should do, is retrieve the `SampleService` from the `ApplicationContext`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DigitalTheaterApplication.class, args);
    ctx.getBean(SampleService.class).sample();
}
```

This will get the Spring created, and proxied, instance, with AOP applied.

Another way, without messing around with the `ApplicationContext` is to create a `CommandLineRunner` which will be executed during startup.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DigitalTheaterApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner tester(SampleService service) {
    return args -> service.sample();
}
```

Something like that will also invoke the `sample` method on the Spring managed instance without having to get it yourself.

Comment: Hi Deinum,  Now I have got a vivid picture. Thanks for you help.